# Resetting password where User set up to have hashed_password

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, authentication

In my Rails app, I set up my users table to have a string for `:email` and `:hashed_password`. However I want to provide the option to reset the password. Following [Railscast 274](http://railscasts.com/episodes/274-remember-me-reset-password), I have everything set up, but the actual password isn't changing to what I reset it as. I thought maybe I'd have to change `:password` to `:hashed_password` in my User model where I handle validations but `:password` works elsewhere so I ruled it out. Can someone help me figure this out?

**Here's my `User` model:**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessor :password
  attr_accessible :email, :password, :password_confirmation    

  before_save :encrypt_new_password
  before_create { generate_token(:auth_token) }
  before_validation :downcase_email

  has_one :profile, :dependent => :destroy

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :profile

  validates :email, :uniqueness => true,
                :length => { :within => 5..50 },
                :format => { :with => /^[^@][\w.-]+@[\w.-]+[.][a-z]{2,4}$/i }
  validates :password, :confirmation => true,
                   :length => { :within => 4..20 },
                   :presence => true,
                   :if => :password_required?

  def self.authenticate(email, password)
    user = find_by_email(email)
    return user if user && user.authenticated?(password)
  end

  def authenticated?(password)
    self.hashed_password == encrypt(password)
  end

  def send_password_reset
    generate_token(:password_reset_token)
    self.password_reset_sent_at = Time.zone.now
    save!
    UserMailer.password_reset(self).deliver
  end

  def generate_token(column)
    begin
      self[column] = SecureRandom.hex
    end while User.exists?(column => self[column])
  end
end
```

**My `password_resets_controller`:**

```
class PasswordResetsController < ApplicationController
  layout "password_reset"

  def new
  end

  def create
    user = User.find_by_email(params[:email])
    if user
      user.send_password_reset
      redirect_to new_password_reset_path, :notice => "Check your email for password reset instructions."
    else
      redirect_to new_password_reset_path, :notice => "Sorry, we couldn't find that email. Please try again."
    end

  end

  def edit
    @user = User.find_by_password_reset_token!(params[:id])
    session[:user_id] = @user.id
  end

  def update
    @user = User.find_by_password_reset_token!(params[:id])
    if @user.password_reset_sent_at < 2.hours.ago
      redirect_to new_password_reset_path, :alert => "Your password reset link has expired."
    elsif @user.update_attributes(params[:user])
      redirect_to profile_path(@user), :notice => "Great news: Your password has been reset."
    else
      render :edit
    end
  end
end
```

**My password_reset form code:**

```
<%= form_for @user, :url => password_reset_path(params[:id]) do |f| %>
  <% if @user.errors.any? %>
  <div id="error_messages">
    <% for message in @user.errors.full_messages %>
    <li class="error"><%= message %></li>
    <% end %>
  </div>
  <% end %>

  <p class="label"><label for="password">New Password:</label></p>
  <p><%= password_field_tag :password, nil, :autofocus => true, :autocomplete => 'off', :placeholder => 'Enter a new password' %></p>
  <p class="label"><label for="password_confirmation">Confirm Password:</label></p>
  <p><%= password_field_tag :password_confirmation, nil, :autofocus => false, :autocomplete => 'off', :placeholder => 'Reenter your new password' %></p>

  <%= submit_tag 'Update Password', :class => 'button orange' %>

<% end %>
```

**My `users_controller` update action:**

```
def update
  @user = current_user
  if @user.update_attributes(params[:user])
    redirect_to settings_path, :notice => 'Updated user information successfully.'
  else
    render :action => 'edit'
  end
end
```

**My server message when I update my password:**

```
Started POST "/password_resets/56be9c1168637d64eaa42b2551ef9b6c" for 127.0.0.1 at Thu Mar 08 19:36:03 -0500 2012
  Processing by PasswordResetsController#update as HTML
  Parameters: {"commit"=>"Update Password", "password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]", "authenticity_token"=>"N8v69nP9NbaGVGdYwmv6EF8uIp4/Vqld/y+Q2K40CMQ=", "utf8"=>"\342\234\223", "id"=>"56be9c1168637d64eaa42b2551ef9b6c", "password"=>"[FILTERED]"}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like because you're using `password_field_tag`, the parameters are ignored when the user model is updated.  Try using `f.password_field` instead so that the password params are nested in `params[:user]`.

Alternatively, you could also call `if @user.update_attributes(:password => params[:password], :password_confirmation => params[:password_confirmation])` in the PasswordResetsController.

Comment: That did it. You have no idea how long I've been trying to figure that out. Is there anywhere I can read more about the `password_field_tag` and params?

Comment: Awesome!  Glad that helped.  Here's links to the api docs for [password_field](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-password_field)

Comment: Thanks. I have no idea why but the docs are so confusing to me most of the time. They just don't seem to be written for beginners. Now if only I could figure out why JS doesn't work with a mobile MIME type!

Answer (score 1):

Don't forget to change submit_tag to f.submit